# PrimeFaces p:accordionPanel inside ui:repeat or c:forEach

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, accordion, uirepeat

I'm trying  to create multiple `accordionPanel`s. 
I tried to include this tag inside repeat elements (e.g. `c:forEach`).
The `accordionPanel` is well rendered, but I'm unable to switch from one tab to another.

These are some codes I tried:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{myBackingBean.myList}" var="o">
    <p:accordionPanel dynamic="true" cache="true" multiple="true" widgetVar="accordion">
        <p:tab title="Title 1">
            #{o.data_one}
        </p:tab>
        <p:tab title="Title 2">
            #{o.data_two}
        </p:tab>
    </p:accordionPanel>
</ui:repeat>
```

And also

```
<c:forEach items"${myBackingBean.myList}" var="o">
    <p:accordionPanel dynamic="true" cache="true" multiple="true" widgetVar="accordion">
        <p:tab title="Title 1">
            #{o.data_one}
        </p:tab>
        <p:tab title="Title 2">
            #{o.data_two}
        </p:tab>
    </p:accordionPanel>
</ui:repeat>
```

Both of these codes produces a list of `accordionPanel`s, each with two tabs.
But I'm unable to switch from one tab to another: If I click one tab it does not open nor close (except for the last `accordionPanel`).

Noteworthy, if I put two or more  `accordionPanel`s by hand (without JSF loops) they works.

Also, I've checked the requests  the browser sends when I try to open/close a tab. The requests I intercept are like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><partial-response><changes><update id="mainForm:tabView"><![CDATA[
// something that always use the id of the HTML tag of the _last_ accordionPanel
</update></changes></partial-response>
```

How can I put an `<accordionPanel>` inside an `<ui:repeat>` or `<c:forEach>` so that I can still switch the `accordionPanel`'s tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the problem with the `widgetVar` when you put `p:accordion` in `ui:repeat`, it will generate Accordion Panel components with different/dynamic Ids but not with different/dynamic `widgetVar` when you explicitly specify `widgetVar` like you're doing in your code.

Which is basically name to Javascript Object to access the Client side Api functions of `p:accordion`.

So If you are not using that `widgetVar` of `p:accordion`s anywhere, **Remove** `widgetVar` attribute, then the `widgetVar` will be generated dynamically.

If you still want to use `widgetVar`, give dynamic name yourself, for example:

```
widgetVar="accordion_#{o.data_one}"
```

*Note: I tried the above strategy with only on `ui:repeat`.

Using:Primefaces 3.5 and JSF 2.1.13 and its working for me.*